# Counting sets by their connectedness

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, generating-functions

Let $U = \{u_1, u_2, \ldots , u_m \}$ where each $u_i$ is an $r$-subset of $[n]$ and 
$\,\bigcup u_i \!=\! [n]$. Construct the intersection graph of $U$. That is, let node $i$ correspond to $u_i$ and add edge $(i,j)$ if $u_i \cap u_j \neq \emptyset$. For example, suppose $n=8$ and $U = \{123, 124, 234, 567, 568\}$. The intersection graph is

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad $ [image]

We notice there are two connected components, ie. $\mathcal{C}(U)=2$. Given $n,r,m$ how many sets have exactly $c$ connected components?

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
T_{n,r,m}(c) &= \displaystyle \left[x^c\right] \sum_{\left|U\right| = m} x^{\mathcal{C}(U)} \\
&= \displaystyle \left[y^m x^c\right] \sum_U y^{\left|U\right|} x^{\mathcal{C}(U)}
\end{array}
$$

Can we come up with an expression for $T_{n,r,m}(c)$ or at least some way to efficiently compute it? I would be happy with an algorithm where $n \le 50, r \le 10$ is tractable. I've enumerated all the [nonzero values for $n\le6$](https://github.com/Turing-Apparatus/Stack_Exchange---Reddit/blob/master/Ramsey/small_cases) to use for verification.

---

I've posted a [partial answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1191748/202838) that reduces the problem to counting $T_{n,r,m}(1)$, the sets with a fully connected graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Notations:** Always fix $r$. Suppose $L=(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_l)$ is a list of non-decreasing natural numbers. Denote by $|L|$ ($=l$) the length of the list and $\sum L = c_1 + \ldots + c_l$ the sum of entries in $L$. Let $T(n, L)$ count the number of sets $U = \{u_1, \ldots, u_{m}\}$, where $m=\sum L$, each $u_i$ is an $r$-subset of $[n]$ and $\cup U = [n]$, whose intersection graph have exactly $l$ connected components with sizes $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_l$.

**Relation with the Old Notation:** $$T_{n,m}(c)=\sum_{|L| = c, \sum{L}=m}T(n, L).$$

**Inductive Property:**

1. If $L = L_1+L_2$ (list concatenation) such that $L_1 < L_2$ (i.e., all entries in $L_1$ is less than the ones in $L_2$), then $$T(n,L)=\sum_{n_1+n_2=n} {n\choose n_1} T(n_1, L_1)T(n_2, L_2).$$
2. Suppose $L = (c,c,\ldots, c) =: (c)^l$, where $l=|L|$. We have $$T(n, L)=\sum_k\sum_{l_1 + \ldots + l_k = l}\frac{1}{l_1!\ldots l_k!}\sum_{\ n_1 < \ldots < n_k}\frac{n!}{(n_1!)^{l_1}\ldots(n_k!)^{l_k}}1_{l_1n_1 + \ldots + l_kn_k=n}T(n_1, (c))^{l_1}\ldots T(n_k, (c))^{l_k}.$$

**Boundary Condition:** $T(n, L)=0$ if $n < r$ or $n > r|L|$.

**Restriction Formula:** Note that the total number of sets $U = \{u_1, \ldots, u_m\}$ each $u_i$ is an $r$-subset of $[n]$ is equal to $${{n\choose r}\choose m}.$$ On the other hand, one can count it using $T_{n,m}(c)$ according to $\cup U$. We get the total number of $U$ is equal to $$\sum_{n_0\leq n}{n\choose n_0}\sum_cT_{n_0, m}(c) = \sum_{n_0\leq n}{n\choose n_0}\sum_l\sum_{|L| = l, \sum{L}=m}T(n_0, L).$$ Therefore we have $$\sum_{n_0\leq n}{n\choose n_0}\sum_l\sum_{|L| = l, \sum{L}=m}T(n_0, L) = {{n\choose r}\choose m}.$$ We rewrite it as $$T(n,(m)) = {{n\choose r}\choose m} - \sum_{n_0 < n}{n\choose n_0}\sum_l\sum_{|L| = l, \sum{L}=m}T(n_0, L) - \sum_{l>1}\sum_{|L| = l, \sum{L}=m}T(n, L)$$

**Punch Line:** Define $(n_0, L_0) < (n, L)$ if $n_0 < n$ or $n_0 = n$ but $|L_0| > |L|$. Clearly, one can use the inductive properties, the boundary condition and the restriction formula to compute $T(n,L)$ once $T(n_0,L_0)$ are given for all $(n_0, L_0)< (n,L)$ (call $(n,L)$ complexity of $T(n,L)$) since in all formulas involved the complexity on the right hand side is always less than the complexity on the left hand side.

**Update:** For computational reasons (as OP mentioned in the comment), one may want to replace the inductive property 2 by a simpler recursion $$T(n,(c)^l)=\sum_{k}{n-1\choose k-1}T(k,(c))T(n-k,(c)^{l-1}).$$ Again the idea in the inductive properties is indeed based on OP's answer.

Comment: Very nice and thank you for taking the time! The trick at the end seems to be what I was missing in my relations (assuming they are error-free). I get $\; T_{n,m} = {{n \choose r} \choose m} - \sum_{c>1} T_{n,m}^{c,\infty} - \sum_{\kappa<n} {n \choose \kappa} \sum_{c} T_{\kappa, m}^{c, \infty}$

Comment: This is actually very similar to my initial idea (partitioning the graph by $L$) which I tried to encapsulate in my recurrences; if you expand the triple summation for $T_{n,m}^{c,\ell}$ you'll see that you end up with every possible partition $L$ in conjunction with your equation (1.). The main difference between our relations is the case when $L=(c,c,\ldots,c)=(c)^l$ where $l>1$. This is your equation (2.) and my equation for $T_{n}^{l \, \times \, c}$.

Comment: In (2.) you specify that there are $l_i$ components that cover $n_i$ elements and you take care of overcounting with the factors $\frac{1}{\prod l_i!}$ and ${n \choose n_1 \ldots n_1 \ldots n_k \ldots n_k} \delta_{\boldsymbol{l} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}, n} $. This looks correct to me. See if you find anything wrong with my idea; we pick the component that covers "1" and then recurse. $ T_{n}^{l \, \times \, c} = \sum_{\kappa < n} {n-1 \choose \kappa-1} \, T_{\kappa,c} \, T_{n-\kappa}^{(l-1) \, \times \, c} $

Comment: This is equivalent to
 $$ \begin{array} {lrl}
T_{n}^{l \, \times \, c} &= \displaystyle \sum_{n_1 + \ldots + n_l=n} & {n-1 \choose n_1-1} {n-n_1-1 \choose n_2-1} \ldots {n-\ldots -n_{l-1} - 1 \choose n_l-1} \, T_{n_1,c} \ldots T_{n_l,c} \\ &= \displaystyle \sum_{n_1 + \ldots + n_l=n} & \displaystyle (n-1)! \prod_i \frac{T_{n_i,c}}{(n_i - 1)! \,\left(\delta_{i,l} + \sum_{j>i} n_j \right)}  \end{array}$$

Comment: You are welcome. My solution is indeed inspired by your partial solution. I just find it more clear for me to think in terms of "list". The real innovation lies in the restriction formula which was missing in your approach.

Comment: Oh I agree, your equations speak more for themselves. I don't like triple sums or four dimensional recurrences either (hence my overcounting mistake). I only wrote it as such for computational reasons. The restriction formula was indeed exactly what I was looking for. Very slick! I don't think I'm going to get a better solution, but in the meantime I'm going to leave the bounty open for visibility.

Comment: Yes, if one thinks about implementation then property 2 should be replaced by what you had in the comments above. I have incorporated your comment in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recently came up with a faster solution to this problem that reduces the recurrence dimension by 1.

Let $T_r(n, m, c)$ represent the number we are looking for, ie. the number of ways to take $m$ subsets of $[n]$ such that each subset has size $r$, the subsets cover $[n]$, and their intersection graph has $c$ connected components. I made $r$ a subscript because it is held fixed throughout. The logic is similar to $T_n^{c \times \ell}$ in my answer above. Consider the connected component that covers the element "1" from the ground set. Suppose it consists of $s$ subsets and that it covers $k$ total elements. There are $\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$ ways to choose the covered elements which leads to the recurrence for $c > 1$.

$$T_r(n, m, c) = \sum_{k} \sum_{s} \binom{n - 1}{k - 1} \; T_r(n\!-\!k, \,m\!-\!s,\,c\!-\!1) \; T_r(k, s, 1) $$

For connected graphs $c = 1$ we get the same restriction formula from before: all the possible graphs given $m$ minus those that don't cover $[n]$ minus those that have more than 1 connected component.

$$ T_r(n, m, 1) \; = \; {{n \choose r} \choose m} \; - \; \sum_{k \, < \, n} \sum_{c} {n \choose k} T_r(k, m, c) \; - \; \sum_{c \, > \, 1} T_r(n, m, c)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer, which reduces the problem to counting $T_{n,r,m}(1)$, that is, counting the number of sets that have a connected intersection graph ($c=1$). The reduction occurs through a recurrence, with $c=1$ corresponding to the base cases. First let me change the notation. Let $r$ be given as before. Since $r$ is held fixed, I suppress it as an index.

$$ \; $$

- $T_{n,m}^{c,\ell}$ : This is the same as the old notation $T_{n,r,m}(c)$ with the added constraint that each connected component has less than $\ell$ nodes.
- $T_{n}^{c\,\times\,\ell}$ : constrains the graph to have exactly $c$ connected components of size $\ell$. The number of nodes is suppressed as an index since it is forced to equal $c\ell$.
- $T_{n,m} = T_{n,m}^{1,\, \ell_{ > m}} = T_{n}^{1 \, \times \, m}$ : counts the number of connected graphs on $m$ nodes.

$$ \; $$

Remember that for all three of these, each node corresponds to an $r$-subset and their union must equal $[n]$. To compute $T_{n,m}^{c,\ell}$, let $\gamma$ denote the size of the largest connected component, let $\varsigma$ be the number of components of size $\gamma$, let $\kappa$ be the the number of elements covered by such components, and then recurse.

$$
T_{n,m}^{c,\ell} = \sum_{\gamma \,<\, \ell} \; \sum_{\varsigma \,\le\, c} \; \sum_{\kappa \, \le \, n}
{n \choose \kappa}\; 
T_{\kappa}^{\varsigma \, \times \, \gamma} \; T_{n-\kappa,\,m-\gamma\varsigma}^{c-\varsigma,\,\gamma}
$$

Note the summation limits can often be pruned. The ${n \choose \kappa}$ picks the elements of $[n]$ covered by the large components. To compute $T_{n}^{c \, \times \ell}$ for $c>1$ we enforce that the "first" component to be the one that covers element "1" and we suppose that it covers $\kappa$ total elements. Then we recurse.

$$ T_{n}^{c \, \times \, \ell} = \sum_{\kappa \, < \, n} {n-1 \choose \kappa - 1} \; T_{\kappa, \ell} \; T_{n-\kappa}^{(c-1) \, \times \, \ell}  $$

Thus the problem has been reduced to counting the connected graphs $T_{n,m}$.

**Update** @roy's restriction formula: by summing over $c$ and picking out the term $T_{n,m}$ we get the expression

$$ T_{n,m} \; = \; {{n \choose r} \choose m} \; - \; \sum_{\kappa \, < \, n} \sum_{c} {n \choose \kappa} T_{\kappa,m}^{c, \infty} \; - \; \sum_{c \, > \, 1} T_{n,m}^{c,\infty}$$

note the third term on the RHS does not produce a $T_{n,m}$ (so there is no cancellation).

Comment: I am a bit confused by your formula on $T_n^{c\times l}$.  How do you specify "the first component"? It is not clear to me that there is an order between the components. When there are two components of size $k$, it seems the formula is over-counting.

Comment: @roy_24601 You are right. It seems I imposed an ordering on the nodes and then forgot to enforce it in $T_{n}^{c \, \times \, \ell}$. Which means I should get rid of $\frac{1}{\varsigma!} {m \choose \gamma\varsigma} {\gamma\varsigma \choose \gamma \ldots \gamma}$ in the formula for $T_{n,m}^{c,\ell}$. Now for $T_{n}^{c \, \times \, \ell}$, if I enforce that the "first" component contains the smallest element in the ground set "[n]", then the multiplicative factor becomes ${n \choose \kappa-1}$. I think this is correct. I have yet to read your answer so give me a moment.

Comment: Whoops should be ${n-1 \choose \kappa-1}$

Comment: It looks correct to me now. Nice fix!

Comment: @roy_24601 I've verified the recurrences btw (they match the brute-forced values that I listed). If you're interested, here is the [code](https://github.com/Turing-Apparatus/Stack_Exchange---Reddit/blob/master/Ramsey/rec_Trnmc.py) and all the [values for $r=2, n\le20$](https://github.com/Turing-Apparatus/Stack_Exchange---Reddit/blob/master/Ramsey/req2).

Comment: Cool. Hope your project goes well.